# how to avoid SCSS from recognizing slash symbol as a Division in a function

Tags: sass

I'm using  SCSS (sass) and there is a problem whenever I use a function with input variables if the variables are being used with a slash symbol (/) they will be recognized as Equation
here I have 2 examples for you so in the first one I used a **slash** symbol (/) and it's **considered** as a **division**
and the next one I used percent (%)and it considers as a mod instead of a simple percentage
**so how can you avoid it being considered as an Equation?**
here is some example :

```
 @mixin grid_column_row($column_1,$column_2,$row_1,$row_2) {
      grid-column: ($column_1)/($column_2);
      grid-row: ($row_1)/($row_2);
  }
```

in this example I want this to be considered as a normal grid-row and grid-column like :
grid-row:1/3;
grid-colmun:6/12;
**not** as a **division** like :
grid-row: **0.33**;(  1/3)
grid-colmun :**0.5**;  (6/12)

and second example with percentage (%) :

```
@mixin font-size_p($percent) {
    font-size: $percent% ;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried using () or ""  and including my variables inside them and then by doing this avoid them from being considered as an equation but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first mixin, you need to use [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation):

```
@mixin grid_column_row($column_1,$column_2,$row_1,$row_2) {
   grid-column: #{$column_1}/#{$column_2};
   grid-row: #{$row_1}/#{$row_2};
}
```

For your second mixin, as indicated in the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/numbers#units):

> Percentages in Sass work just like every other unit. They are not interchangeable with decimals, because in CSS decimals and percentages mean different things. For example, `50%` is a number with `%` as its unit, and Sass considers it different than the number `0.5`.
>
> You can convert between decimals and percentages using unit arithmetic. `math.div($percentage, 100%)` will return the corresponding decimal, and `$decimal * 100%` will return the corresponding percentage. You can also use the [`math.percentage()` function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#percentage) as a more explicit way of writing `$decimal * 100%`.

You can write your mixin as:

```
@mixin font-size_p($percent) {
   // Or + 0%, depending on how your want to write your percentage values
   font-size: $percent + 100%;
}
```

Or like this:

```
@mixin font-size_p($percent) {
   font-size: math.percentage($percent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a sass library made for that use case (You can use [list.slash()] to force **/** to be used as a separator):

```
@use "sass:list";
@mixin grid_column_row($column_1,$column_2,$row_1,$row_2) {
    grid-column: list.slash($column_1, $column_2);
    grid-row: list.slash($row_1, $row_2);
}
```

And second case you can use the library math:

```
@use "sass:math";

math.percentage($number) // converts number to a percentage number
```